# Detecting Push Notifications Showed on iOS device screen when our app was running with swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

The thing is we don't want to interact with push notifications. The one thing we want to do is to detect when device has received one while out app was active.

We are going to use this detected information to change screen brightness for example.

The thing is we just want to detect the ones shows on the screen by iOS.

if we use this in in AppDelegate.swift to get permission.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        if granted {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

and that to detect and to do something when received notification.

```
 func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {


}
```

Application asks permission showing

"App Name" Would Like to Send You Notifications

message.

But we do not want to send notification we just want to detect any notification showed on screen by iOS when our app was running.

Comment: You mean notifications sent to some other app?  You can't. There is no information provided to your app on what other apps are doing.

Comment: Send by an other app, I mean SMS notification for example.

Comment: So no, your app does not get any indication of notifications shown by iOS for other reasons

Comment: So we can not detect neither notification received by iOS or when message views shown on screen  in some way. This is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no indication to your app when iOS displays a notification from another app if the user does not interact with it; the notification is simply overlaid on top of your screen.

If the user taps the notification then the usual app delegate methods will fire as your app moves to the background and then suspended state

Comment: Yeah I think this is the situation, I wanted the change brightness of screen when a notification received when my app was foreground. Because of my app's nature it would be cool.